# Why can't we define fundamental unit of mass?

Tags: mass, conventions, definition, si-units, metrology

In my physics textbook of class $11^{th}$ The kilogram was defined as :-

> **mass of the platinum-iridium standard cylinder kept at Sevre's France**

But this isn't a proper and scientific definition of an important fundamental unit.
When we have advanced so much in atomic physics that we are creating matter, Then why are we unable to define unit of mass?

Comment: @JohnForkosh i am small to understand that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we still not have an exact (constants-based) definition for a kilogram?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32120/)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sorry but title was not clear so this happened

Comment: @Abhishek No need to apologize, asking duplicates is just something that happens.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty My question was genuine but its ok

Comment: @Abhishek It's perfectly OK to have genuine questions, but if there's already a version that's essentially the same then it's inefficient to keep both versions open. If the answers to the *existing* question are insufficient then you should edit this question to explain why, and it can be reopened. If they do, then this can just stay closed and it's not a problem.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty can we merge the questions?

Comment: It is possible but not necessarily appropriate. If you want to do that, raise a custom moderator flag asking whether it's suitable in this case. (The response will be in the [flags page in your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/196716).) Basically, merging is appropriate when the answers to the *new* question are seamless answers to the old one. And really, in this case, there's no actual need for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mass is the last fundamental unit that is still defined like that.

Previously, meter was also defined as the length of a specific item, kept also at Sevres, in France (since the metric system has been popularized starting from France).

But the issue with mass, is that mass and energy are kind of interchangeable, so that defining a mass unit by using specific atoms is very tricky if you want the definition to be usable everywhere, that is fairly easily reproductible with an experiment method.

The current definition of the meter is not very easy to use, but it fairly accessible and absolutely reliable and reproductible.

The next definition of mass unit, as per the existing answer, is not using the same path, an rely on a fundamental constant and leverage on the meter, that can be defined precisely with a experiment method.

Answer (score 11):

The definition of the kilogram is to be changed in 2019, see [Proposed redefinition of SI base units (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_redefinition_of_SI_base_units#Kilogram).

The current proposal is to indirectly define the kilogram via an exact specification of the Planck constant: this is possible because the dimension of that constant can be expressed as a combination of mass, time and distance. The kilogram would then be defined via the second and the meter.

Comment: is it nice for a definition to depend on other definitions?

Comment: How would you do otherwise?

Comment: using exact value of avogadro's number?

Comment: So you would be using the definition of the mole.

Comment: mole is simpler than others

Comment: This is an interesting discussion, but comments are not meant for that. I suggest you ask a new question about this.

Comment: @Abhishek Using an exact definition of Avogadro's number is also a proposed definition / part of the solution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant#International_Avogadro_Coordination

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin then my reputation will decrease but i love arguing

Comment: @Abhishek [There is a chat for that.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar)